# firebase remote config fetch no answer

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

Is it possible to get Firebase remote config before starting an activity ?

I'm trying to get Firebase remote config inside a background IntentService before activity is started but onComplete() is never called.

FirebaseRemoteConfig instance stays in status FirebaseRemoteConfigInfo.LAST_FETCH_STATUS_NO_FETCH_YET

Answer (score 0):

A fetch will take as long as a fetch takes.  You get no guarantee about how long it will take, just like any other request to a server over a network.  Your app should be prepared to work with default values you specify, or make your users wait for the fetch by using a splash screen that only advances when your fetch is done (this is not usually a good idea - better to work with defaults until the first fetch completes).